# d3.extent creates collisions between x-axis and graph's point labels when plotted with constraint relaxation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a scatterplot that uses constraint relaxation to de-conflict the labels for the points that it graphs ([Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mb7L9QH6bQGHGtqdMyKx?p=preview)). The problem is that, when I relax the constraints, this causes collisions between the point labels and the x-axis labels. The axes are generated using d3.extent and d3.scale.linear.

I've tried to de-conflict the point labels and the x-axis by extending the length of the y-axis, but the closest I've come to achieving this is by changing the original value of `0` to `30` in the following stanza:

```
var yext = d3.extent(data, d => d[1]);
var sy = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain(yext)
  .range([height, 30]) // flip y-axis
  .nice();
```

The result is less than ideal, leaving an awkward gap instead of an intersection between the x and y axes:
[image: How the scatterplot looks now]

What I want to achieve is something like this:
[image]

(Except I want to achieve this through code, rather than Photoshop).

Can anyone demonstrate a solution? ([Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mb7L9QH6bQGHGtqdMyKx?p=preview))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add a padding in the domain? Like:

```
.domain([yext[0] * 0.95, yext[1] * 1.05])
//less here---------^-- more here----^
```

Here is the plunker with that solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/rKArjn7DwQa9g1X5CaNW?p=preview